# Installing software on Linux using the terminal

Tags: linux, terminal, installation

I am trying to install a software(P4V) through the linux command window, but I am not sure the best way to go about it since I am new to the linux environment. I downloaded the set up file on my current windows machine and uploaded to a network drive. The linux also has accessed to this network drive, but I forgot how to access files on the network drive via linux. Any other way to install the software would also be appreciated. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Typically, installing software on Linux involves the same steps steps:

```
tar -xvf the_program.tar.gz
cd the_program
./configure
make
make install (as privileged user, as necessary)
```

If your system has the necessary libraries required by the executable, the program will/should compile and run.

[Here is a link for Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/25961/how-to-install-a-tar-gz-or-tar-bz2-file)

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is, please check this package in package manager repository.
This is an easiest way.

I think you are not a black belt linux user.
You can see this link the package managers based on distro.

http://www.linuxplanet.com/linuxplanet/tutorials/6546/1

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Ubuntu & package extension is .deb then do,

```
$ sudo dpkg -i /path/to/package.deb
```

Better to find the repository in Ubuntu & use of command

```
$ sudo apt-get install [packagename]
```

Similarly if the distribution is Fedora based, use

```
$ yum install [packagename]
```

The tar file you can install in the way metioned in above answer by Tyler Jandreau